# Record user entry on Android App developed under Unity and deployed on Google Play

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I wrote an Android app using Unity and will deploy it using Google Play (only alpha or beta release). The purpose of this application is for research therefore there is no unethical situation in this scenario.

I would like to record every single user actions on my app, including which buttons were pressed, how long the user spent on a screen and various interactive elements of my app.

I can probably easily write a log file under Unity with all those information but I doubt I will be allowed to send myself some data using online feature (legal ?)

How was wondering if instead, Google Development platform had some type of Data Analytic section that will allow to record those data?

Comment: Are the official docs for android and unity not answering your question?

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

https://unity3d.com/solutions/analytics

Comment: Yes, indeed. Somehow I found that after posting the question. Thank you for confirming.